# Cast int to SmallDateTime

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, casting, smalldatetime

I am trying to compare `L.LoanDueDate` (which is a `smalldatetime`) to the return value of `ufnARCUGetLatestProcessDate()` (which is an `int`) to see how many days the loan due date is past the last process date.

I receive an

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type smalldatetime

error and can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be useful. Thank you in advance.

```
CAST(L.LoanDueDate - CAST(CAST((SELECT ProcessDate FROM ufnARCUGetLatestProcessDate()) AS VARCHAR(10)) AS smalldatetime) AS INT)
```

Comment: I have also tried to use the following.    CAST(L.LoanDueDate-CONVERT(smalldatetime,convert(char(8),(SELECT ProcessDate FROM ufnARCUGetLatestProcessDate()))) AS INT)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out the issue. DigCamare's comment on DATEDIFF reminded me that is what I needed to do even though you can cast a int to a smalldatetime so you can compare it.

```
DATEDIFF(d,L.LoanDueDate,CONVERT(smalldatetime,convert(varchar(10),(SELECT ProcessDate FROM ufnARCUGetLatestProcessDate()))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare an int to a smalldatetime. You need to compare two dates and for that you'd have to use [datediff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the date column to int. It will give you the aproximate (rounded) date, without the time part, as an int.

**Edit:**

This will give you the date as a number for you to compare:

```
SELECT FLOOR(CAST(L.LoanDueDate as float)) -
(SELECT ProcessDate FROM ufnARCUGetLatestProcessDate()) AS myValue
FROM ...
```

The key is to cast the date to number and not the number to date.

Comment: That is why I am trying to cast it to a char first then getting the small date value from that. All i need is the date, no time.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add the following. This is what I am using to do a simple int to smalldatetime conversion. Hope it helps other people.

```
(SELECT CAST(CAST(ProcessDate AS VARCHAR(10)) AS SMALLDATETIME) FROM ufnARCUGetLatestProcessDate())
```